# Unwanted removal of decimal points from list of double after calculation

Tags: vb.net

Using MS VS 2013 (VB.net) with SQL Server 2012.

I am querying a database and returning a list of double using a stored procedure.  I am then dividing each double by 8760.  When the first list returns from the database it has the decimal places.  The list looks like this

[image]

After the calc has been performed the decimals have been removed.  See image below.

[image]

As you can see the decimals are removed.  As if you take the first one and divide it by 8760 you get 101.27  Anyone know why or how to avoid this?

My code is as follows

```
Dim hoursInYear As Double = 8760
Dim steamFees As List(Of Double)
Dim steamFee As Double
Dim steamFeePerHour As New List(Of Double)
Dim steamFeeTotal As Double
steamFees = RunDetailsCalculations.getFixedFeesSteam


For Each steamFee In steamFees
    steamFeePerHour.Add(steamFee \ hoursInYear)
Next

steamFeeTotal = steamFeePerHour.Sum
```

Comment: `(steamFee \ hoursInYear)` is integer division which removes decimals

Comment: While it is strange that someone uses the \-operator when he doesn't know it's functionality, this question is perfectly valid and should not be closed as off-topic because it's "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the backslash (`\`) operator, which is for integer division.  Integer division always results in an integer (no fractional part).  If you want to retain the fractional part after the division, you need to use floating-point division, which is the forward slash (`/`) operator.

As the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx) states:

> Integer division is carried out using the \ Operator (Visual Basic). Integer division returns the quotient, that is, the integer that represents the number of times the divisor can divide into the dividend without consideration of any remainder. Both the divisor and the dividend must be integral types (SByte, Byte, Short, UShort, Integer, UInteger, Long, and ULong) for this operator. All other types must be converted to an integral type first.

In other words, when you do this:

```
Dim result As Double = 887146.6 \ 8760
```

What you are really doing is this:

```
Dim input1 As Integer = CInt(887146.6)    ' 887146
Dim input2 As Integer = 8760
Dim result1 As Integer = input1 \ input2  ' 887146 \ 8760 = 101 (the remainder is dropped)
Dim result2 As Double = CDbl(result1)     ' 101.0D
```

Or, more simply:

```
Dim result As Double = CDbl(CInt(887146.6) \ 8760)
```